# How many $6$ digit numbers have their digits in increasing order?

Tags: combinatorics

I can calculate the amount of ways you can choose $6$ digits out of $($1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$)$, but this would include combinations where there are $2$ or more of the same digit.

Comment: @Robert: a 6-digit number is usually understood to be $\ge 100000$. Since the digits have to be increasing, there can't be a $0$ in there.

Comment: I would start by thinking about what you can't have as your first digit. For example you can't have 5. Since 56789 is not a 6 digit number. Same goes for 6789 and thus you can't start with 6. Then for the ones you can have consider their possibilities separately from one another. One of them is trivial. Not sure if it's the best way. Just how I see it right now.

Comment: is it strictly increasing? for example 888889 is allowed or not allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fairly straightfoward way to find this out.
The key point is that there is only one possible arrangement in increasing order for $6$ given numbers.
This means that you just simply have to find out how many $6$ digit numbers are there.
Assuming that you want all of them (even with repeated digits),
there are $10$ choices for each digit. However, the first digit cannot be $0$.
Therefore, we have
$$9\times 10^5=900000$$
such possible numbers.
If you want only distinct digits, you can breakdown the question to choosing $6$ numbers from $10$ numbers. There are ${10\choose 6}=210$ ways to do so. However, $0$ cannot be in the first place.
So, we just subtract these cases.
There are ${9\choose 5}=126$ such cases.
Hence, the answer is
$$210-126=84$$

Comment: They need to be in a strictly increasing order, thus no repetitions.

Comment: @JohnDoe , By repetitions I mean repeating digits. For example $112233$ has repeating digits whereas $123456$ has distinct digits.

Comment: @AvZ: Yes, and John Doe has said that that's not what he wants. (This was already implicit in the original question, but it could have been stated more forcefully.)

Comment: Editted answer accordingly.

Comment: Somewhere while reading the answers, I realized the solution myself. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnDoe: How amazing! You read all these answers, that were _specifically designed_ to help you see the solution; and you saw the solution, all by yourself! Your comment looks a little ungrateful to me.

Comment: I took the long way around for the sake of explaination. The answer is simply ${9\choose 6}=84$ as there cannot be a $0$ in the number.

Comment: I am ungrateful by using user input to help reach a conclusion by myself and then giving due credit to the ones that helped me?

Comment: @JohnDoe: "I realized the solution myself." Perhaps you are not a native English speaker, in which case I apologise.

Comment: I am not. While I see how that sentence might sound, eh, unmindful, I think it was made obvious that I was not using it in a condescending way. Either way, it's cool.

Answer (score 4):

Take the sequence of numbers $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)$ and simply get rid of three of them.  How many ways can you do this?  It is equivalent to ask how many subsets of three elements you can take from a set of nine elements.  So the answer is $${9\choose 3}=84.$$

Comment: That's an interesting way to think about it. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

Answers to the following two questions should help.

1.How many ways can you first choose 6 different digits from that set?

2.Given that you have chosen 6 digits how many ways can you arrange them so they are in increasing order?